# How do you access Android credential storage?

Tags: android, certificate, credentials

In Settings > Location & Security there is a section that allows the user to import certificates. There is also an option, ["Use secure credentials"](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=168578#1089481) that "Allow[s] applications to access secure certificates and other credentials". I can find no mention of how to get to this in the documentation, and very few mentions of it online aside from people using it to connect to certificate-secured wifi networks. One of the only [pertinent things](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/N9FOSkRSpdc/discussion) I found was a post claiming that accessing these certificates was actually impossible for regular apps. Is this true? Does anyone know how to access these certificates if it isn't or documentation somewhere that states it is not possible?

Comment: Only documented stuff I've found about credentials: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html . I know it's likely not related to what you're looking for and I'm quite interested in knowing the answer!!

Comment: As far as I can tell that has to do with Android's account management functionality. It works pretty well for Facebook and Twitter and the like, but I don't think it supports certificates from that section of the settings UI. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: You won't be able to access these certificates from an app, and the only thing you can use them for is WiFi and VPN anyway.  If you need to establish trust within your own app, you can create your own KeyStore. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html

Comment: @Brandon - I wish they wouldn't have stated on the option that Applications can access it then, as that makes for a lot of explaining to do. Do you have any source I could point to that says apps can't access it? Also, if you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this Android Issue for some discussion on the topic:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11231

The Settings screen for installing root certificates can only be used for VPN and WiFi, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunate that it is not supported, but thank you for the answer and the source!